# Check Multiple conditions in Ansible include

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

My ansible role has this main.yml

```
more tasks/main.yml
---

- include: ssl_pull.yml
  when: ACTION == 'renewal'
- include: ssl_gen.yml
  when: ACTION == 'generate'
- include: ssl_push.yml
  when: ACTION == 'install'
- include: ssl_install.yml
  when: ACTION == 'install'
```

I want the to give the user the ability to pass multiple ACTION like renewal & install so it includes

```
- include: ssl_pull.yml
- include: ssl_push.yml
- include: ssl_install.yml
```

I know how to pass a single value for ACTION variable as below

```
ansible-playbook -v -i  /web/hosts.txt site.yml -e "ACTION=renewal"
```

How, can i pass either one or multiple values and include files based on the value/s passed ?

Can you please suggest what changes i need to make to my command / yml ?

Comment: Isn't that what tags were implemented for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are [Tags](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html) what you are looking for?

You tag the tasks like:

```
- include: ssl_pull.yml
  tags: renewal

- include: ssl_push.yml
  tags: install

- include: ssl_install.yml
  tags: install
```

Then specify the tags using the `-t` argument:

```
ansible-playbook -v -i  /web/hosts.txt site.yml -t "renewal,generate"
```

---

If you can't use tags for some reasons, we can also do something similar with vars.

Specify the var as comma separated values:

```
ansible-playbook -v -i  /web/hosts.txt site.yml -e "ACTIONS=renewal,generate"
```

And update the condition to split the var by comma:

```
- include: ssl_pull.yml
  when: "'renewal' in ACTIONS.split(',')"
```

Comment: My site.yml does not have the include. It has three roles and each of these roles main.yml has the include statement.

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: You are amazing.. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

[Ansible tags](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html) are designed to do this kind of task selection.

---

If you **really** want to not use tags, you can pass a JSON object in extra-vars:

```
ansible-playbook --inventory-file /web/hosts.txt site.yml \
                 --extra-vars '{"ACTIONS": ["renewal", "install"]}'
```

Then test against an array:

```
- include: ssl_pull.yml
  when: "'renewal' in ACTIONS"
```